# passing id from one page to another page

Tags: visualforce

```
 <apex:commandButton value="Search"  action="{!testing}"/>
```

class

```
public PageReference testing() {
   system.debug('testing');
   PageReference pageref= new pagereference('/apex/recorddetail?recordID');
   pageref.setRedirect(true);
   return pageref;
}
```

In this second page,if i tired to get the current id,id is coming null;

Comment: in pagereference `new pagereference('/apex/recorddetail?recordID='+PassId);` in passId just pass the actual Id then you will get the Id in second page.

Comment: @sfdcweb It could be an answer to the question...

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
   PageReference pageref = new pagereference('/apex/recorddetail');
   pageref.getParameters().put('recordID', YOURRECORDID);
   pageref.setRedirect(true);
   return pageref;
```

Then in your other page's controller:

```
Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('recordID');
```

Comment: its not working in my case